# Accurate conversion between timeval and microseconds

Tags: c, linux, time, glibc

Say `t = 8.376600;`

If I calculate `tv` by:

```
tv->tv_sec = (long) floor (time);
tv->tv_usec = (long) ((time - tv->tv_sec) * 1000000);
```

Then `tv->tv_sec == 8` and `tv->tv_usec == 376599`.

`printf("%f %ld.%06ld\n", time, tv->tv_sec, tv->tv_usec);` prints 
`8.376600 8.376599`.

Is there any simple way I can make the two outputs identical ?

Comment: I assume `t` is a `double`? This looks like round off error. Try: `tv->tv_usec = (long) round((t - tv.tv_sec) * 1000000);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, you round the value down whereas `printf` rounds it to the nearest microsecond.

Here is an alternative version:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

void set_timespec(struct timespec *tv, double time) {
    long long usec = round(time * 1000000);
    tv->tv_sec = usec / 1000000;
    tv->tv_usec = usec % 1000000;
}
```